# Unable to call child methods in model method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, methods, each

I'm having a real struggle with this:

In student.rb:

```
  def subject_avg
    self.goals.each do |goal|
      goal.subject_id
    end
  end
```

This doesn't 'do' anything - or I should say it doesn't do anything different from

```
  def subject_avg
    self.goals.each do |goal|
      goal.id
    end
  end
```

or

```
  def subject_avg
    self.goals.each do |goal|
      goal.goal
    end
  end
```

no matter what, it returns an array of goals that belong to the subject:

```
[
  #<Goal id: 28, goal: "Do it on command", subject_id: 10, created_at: "2013-08-25 10:59:35", updated_at: "2013-08-25 10:59:35", default: nil>, 
  #<Goal id: 29, goal: "Make it chunky", subject_id: 10, created_at: "2013-08-25 10:59:35", updated_at: "2013-08-25 10:59:35", default: nil>, 
  #<Goal id: 30, goal: "Hit the mark", subject_id: 10, created_at: "2013-08-25 10:59:35", updated_at: "2013-08-25 10:59:35", default: nil>, 
  #<Goal id: 31, goal: "Puke and rally", subject_id: 10, created_at: "2013-08-25 10:59:35", updated_at: "2013-08-25 10:59:35", default: nil>
]
```

at first I thought it just wasn't reading/couldn't read the each block for some reason so was just passing the result of `self.goals.each` (although that does seem to be what's happening).  However, if i call a non-existent method, it throws an error:

```
  def subject_avg
    self.goals.each do |goal|
      goal.FFS_do_something!
    end
  end
```

returns

```
undefined method `FFS_do_something!' for #<Goal:0x000001064329f0>
```

if I put the same each block in the view, it works as expected (I can call methods on 'goal' within the each block)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need `map` instead of `each`

```
  def subject_avg
    self.goals.map do |goal|
      goal.subject_id
    end
  end
```

or

```
  def subject_avg
    self.goals.map(&:subject_id)
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

It does something - it returns the array `self.goals` which is correct behaviour. What you wanted to do is to use `map` instead of `each`.